# WSO2 ESB How to see the outsequence log

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have wrote a proxy in WSO2 ESB. using the log files or the Monitor functionality I can see the logs for all the message mediation in the inSequence sequence mediator, but I can't find the logs for the outSequence. My Proxy example is:

```
 <proxy name="FlightStatusService"
          transports="https http"
          startOnLoad="true"
          trace="enable">
      <description/>
      <target>
         <inSequence>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            <property name="TIME_1"
                      expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"
                      scope="default"
                      type="LONG"/>
            <property xmlns:air="http://airline.services.esb.wso2.packt.com"
                      name="airlineInTransport"
                      expression="fn:concat('Airline Company - ', //air:updateStatus/air:airline)"
                      scope="transport"/>
            <property name="airlineInDefault"
                      expression="get-property('transport','airlineInTransport')"
                      scope="default"/>
            <switch xmlns:air="http://airline.services.esb.wso2.packt.com"
                    source="//air:updateStatus/air:airline">
               <case regex="EK">
                  <event topic="flightStatus/emirates"/>
               </case>
               <case regex="AA">
                  <event topic="flightStatus/aa"/>
               </case>
               <case regex="DL">
                  <event topic="flightStatus/delta"/>
               </case>
               <default>
                  <log level="custom">
                     <property name="noAirline" value="There is no Airline with these letters"/>
                  </log>
               </default>
            </switch>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence>
            <property name="TIME_2"
                      expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"
                      scope="default"
                      type="LONG"/>
            <script language="js">var time1 = mc.getProperty("TIME_1");
var time2 = mc.getProperty("TIME_2");
var timeTaken = time2 - time1;
print("--------------  " + timeTaken + " ms  -----------------");
mc.setProperty("RESPONSE_TIME", timeTaken);</script>
            <log level="full" category="DEBUG">
               <property name="airlineInTransport"
                         expression="get-property('default', 'airlineInDefault')"/>
               <property name="Time Duration in ms: " expression="get-property('RESPONSE_TIME')"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
         </outSequence>
    </proxy>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your proxy is support for [OUT_ONLY](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-OUT_ONLY) Activity, outSequence will not get hit.

EDITED -> Added a proxy for reference

Please refer the proxy

```
<proxy name="FlightStatusService"
              transports="https http"
              startOnLoad="true"
              trace="enable">
          <description/>
          <target>
             <inSequence>
                <property name="TIME_1"
                          expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"
                          scope="default"
                          type="LONG"/>
                <property xmlns:air="http://airline.services.esb.wso2.packt.com"
                          name="airlineInTransport"
                          expression="fn:concat('Airline Company - ', //air:updateStatus/air:airline)"
                          scope="transport"/>
                <property name="airlineInDefault"
                          expression="get-property('transport','airlineInTransport')"
                          scope="default"/>
                <switch xmlns:air="http://airline.services.esb.wso2.packt.com"
                        source="//air:updateStatus/air:airline">
                   <case regex="EK">
                      <event topic="flightStatus/emirates"/>
                   </case>
                   <case regex="AA">
                      <event topic="flightStatus/aa"/>
                   </case>
                   <case regex="DL">
                      <event topic="flightStatus/delta"/>
                   </case>
                   <default>
                      <log level="custom">
                         <property name="noAirline" value="There is no Airline with these letters"/>
                      </log>
                   </default>
                </switch>
                <loopback/>
             </inSequence>
             <outSequence>
                <property name="TIME_2"
                          expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"
                          scope="default"
                          type="LONG"/>
                <script language="js">var time1 = mc.getProperty("TIME_1");
    var time2 = mc.getProperty("TIME_2");
    var timeTaken = time2 - time1;
    print("--------------  " + timeTaken + " ms  -----------------");
    mc.setProperty("RESPONSE_TIME", timeTaken);</script>
                <log level="full" category="DEBUG">
                   <property name="airlineInTransport"
                             expression="get-property('default', 'airlineInDefault')"/>
                   <property name="Time Duration in ms: " expression="get-property('RESPONSE_TIME')"/>
                </log>
                <send/>
             </outSequence>
        </proxy>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Vanji. I began working with an example and I modified it to achieve a functionality without caring with the previous configuration.

Comment: Hi Vanji, I thing it was still too early to sing my praises :( I can't see the outsequence log although I removed the OUT_ONLY and FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED property mediators. 
Any other tip or advise?

Comment: Hi Pymoo, the basic flow of the mediation is client(Sends request) -> InSquence-> Backend -> (Response received) Out Sequence. In your case, you do not have the Backend. Therefore, Outsquecen will not be get engaged. Therefore use Loopback mediator[1] to engage the outsquence. This feature is supported WSO2 ESB 480 onwards  [1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Loopback+Mediator

Comment: Also not luck with loopback mediator, I can't fix this example to make the out sequence works, may be there are any problem with it. Maybe I should try something different. Any other advice? Thank you for your time Vanji.

Comment: Hi Pymoo,Please refer the added proxy! in default use case it will hit the Outsequence